# how do i apply Onselect method to drop down menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using twitter bootstrap to create a drop down menu, the menu contains 2 sub-menus as shown:

```
    <div class="Menu"">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="someaction" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Select Action
  <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a class="remove">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Using JavaScript how do i add actions to each sub menus, so for example when i select Add it should alert me "Add" and when i click remove it should alert me "Remove". I think if loop will do a job for me, for example  if (Add is selected do this else if Remove is selected do something else .. i would like to use this to perform different actions based on sub menus

```
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selector` that you are using is perfectly alright, But since you are adding a `click` event to an `anchor` tag, You can optionally use `.preventDefault()` to prevent the page redirecting,

Just try,

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**Note:** you have to use `.text()` method to retrieve the text inside a tag.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/sGG34/)

Comment: But how do i display alerts based on sub menus?

Comment: @user3195896 The code given above will work for the sub menus too, because we have used descendant selectors here.

Comment: @user3195896 Have a look at the attached demo.

Comment: Ok, what if i want to add some action to a specific menu, for example: if i select add it should invoke some method? Dont i have to write if loop saying if (Add is selected do this else if Remove is selected do something else)

Answer (score 0):

Simply write the following code inside your function

```
alert($(this).text());// returns the current element text
```

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLXsH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9GZQ2/ and can do what you want to do. All you need to do is to change the tasks inside the function for you it will be: alert($(this).text());

```
$(function(){
    $("#ProducterType").change(function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
    $("#Role").change(function(){
       alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```